# Printing the contents of a Restlet web service request

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I am implementing a Restful web service using Restlet - I have not found a way to print the content of the HTTP request. I need to check the content of the http request, to get something like this:

POST http://localhost:8080/students

```
<Student>
 <name>Tony<name/>
 <age>19<age/>
<Student/>
```

I am send a custom object the server resource using the following code

```
ClientResource c = new CLientResource(url);
c.post(student, Student.Class);
```

I tried to get the HTTP request also with wireshark , I did not find any http requests, I only found TCP connections.

Anybody knows how to print the content of the http request either on client or server side?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following on the client side :

```
clientResource.getResponseEntity().getText();
```

From the javadoc :

Converts the representation to a string value. Be careful when using 
 this method as the conversion of large content to a string fully 
 stored in memory can result in OutOfMemoryErrors being thrown.

By the way, HTTP requests are TCP connections.

Comment: I know that the Http request is tcp connection , but usually wireshark identifies the http request as an Http not TCP and you can read the request contents , this is not the case with restlet request. I tried your code but it returns null

Comment: I have no problem watching the payload of my requests using wireshark. Are you sure that there is any XML payload travelling between client and server because the above code works fine for me as well.

Comment: Maybe you have problems with SOP (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). It is typically not to receive anything in those cases. Is your client running in the browser ?

Comment: yes , there is data and the request is processed by the server , but I do not know the type of the payload xml,json ,.. .Restlet serialize the object and I do not set any property to determine the type of the serialization. how to determine it ?

Comment: No , my client is not a browser

Comment: I suggest you attach the Restlet sources and put a breakpoint in ConverterService. There is a function toRepresentation where the serialization takes place using functions like ConverterUtils.getBestHelper and getVariants. You can also force the representation by putting method level annotations, see http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.1/13-restlet/27-restlet/328-restlet.html